# Nginx rewrite - Remove path segments from URL for static assets?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following URL:

`https://example.com/<template>/v1/a/b`

I wanted to rewrite it to `https://example.com/<template>/index.php?v=v1&p1=a&p2=b`, and managed to do so using the regex below.

I also have the following static URLs being called from `index.php`:

`https://example.com/<template>/v1/a/b/assets/images/intro.png`

**How can I redirect all `assets` to their proper location? which is:**

`https://example.com/<template>/assets/...`

Here is my setup so far:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name _;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
      rewrite ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ $1/index.php?a=$2&b=$3 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URIs pointing to assets contain the literal word `/assets/`, you just need a regular expression that matches that part of the URI.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)(/.*)?(/assets/.*)$ {
    try_files $1$3 =404;
}
```

The regular expression captures the first word (using the character class `[^/]` to match anything which is not a `/` character), and everything from the word `assets` to the end of the URI, both of which are subsequently used in the `try_files` statement.

Comment: Thank you for this, but one critical issue remains - I need to capture the first segment *after* the domain so I know in which directory to search for the files. e.g., I need the `template` part of the URL as a variable to use for `try_files`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: The value of template is captured in `$1`.

Comment: Ahh awesome! I was under the impression that `$1` contains the domain for some reason, until I realized that the beginning of the match starts from the `$uri` *after* the domain, thank you!